# Send the values collected by web scraping using CheerioGS to the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

CheerioGS project:
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

I would like to know how I can send the `lineup` values to `Column A` of the spreadsheet and `substitute` for `Column B` of the spreadsheet, I am learning to work with `CheerioGS`

So far I've learned to save the results in `Logger.log()`, but I don't understand how to send them to the spreadsheet cells!

```
function myFunction() {
  const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/08/12/south-america/copa-libertadores/club-olimpia/clube-de-regatas-de-flamengo/3579565/').getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
  
  var lineup = $('#yui-main > div > div > div.content-column > div:nth-child(13) > div.container.left > table > tbody > tr > td.player.large-link > a').each((index, element) => {
                  Logger.log($(element).text())
                  });

  var substitute = $('#yui-main > div > div > div.content-column > div:nth-child(14) > div.container.left > table > tbody > tr > td.player.large-link > p > a').each((index, element) => {
                  Logger.log($(element).text())
                  });
}
```

Comment: What sort of objects are lineup and substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an Example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

  const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/08/12/south-america/copa-libertadores/club-olimpia/clube-de-regatas-de-flamengo/3579565/').getContentText();
  const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
  
  var lineup = $('#yui-main > div > div > div.content-column > div:nth-child(13) > div.container.left > table > tbody > tr > td.player.large-link > a').each((index, element) => {
                  Logger.log($(element).text())
                  sheet.getRange(index+1,1).setValue($(element).text());
                  });

  var substitute = $('#yui-main > div > div > div.content-column > div:nth-child(14) > div.container.left > table > tbody > tr > td.player.large-link > p > a').each((index, element) => {
                  Logger.log($(element).text())
                  sheet.getRange(index+1,2).setValue($(element).text());
                  });
}
```